# How to open an HTML file stored in my internal or external storage using web view in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutterwebviewplugin

Want to open an HTML file stored in my internal or external storage using web view. The html file is dynamic so i cannot save in asset folder.

Comment: Please, show us the code of you trying to do it, first.